# Is there a Hadamard form for 3-point functions?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-equations, greens-functions

Let's say we are trying to solve a wave equation for a scalar field in curved spacetime

\begin{equation}
\Big[\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu +k(x)\Big]\phi(x)=-4\pi \rho (x)
\end{equation}

We are interested in the causal Green's function

\begin{equation}
\Big[\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu +k(x)\Big]G_{\pm}(x,x')=\delta (x,x')
\end{equation}

Any Green's function in curved spacetime can be written in Hadamard form

\begin{equation}
G_{\pm}(x,x')=\theta_{\pm}(x,x')\Big\{U(x,x') \delta(\sigma)+V(x,x')\theta(-\sigma)\Big\}
\end{equation}

where $U$ and $V$ are some smooth functions, $\sigma$ is Synge's world function that measures the distance between $x$ and $x'$ and $\theta_{\pm}$ is a Heaviside function that vanishes if $x$ is in the future/past of $x'$.

My question is: Let's say we want to solve a new equation

\begin{equation}
\Big[\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu +k(x)\Big]H(x,x',x'')=f(x,x',x'')
\end{equation}

for some known source $f(x,x',x'')$. Is there a similar construction for 3-point functions? How could we write $H(x,x',x'')$ explicitely?

Disclaimer: I understand this question is at the edge of just being a math question. However, the use of N-point functions in curved spacetime  is a fundamental part of general relativity and quantum field theory and it is an important technique in physics.